# Updating just insered row - mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

is there a way to update a just insered row in a trigger?
Example:

```
Tables: Plane
        Flight
```

Everytime a flight gets insered

```
   nbr             departure              arrival          plane  route
('CA 000', '2020-02-11T13:10:00', '2020-02-11T15:15:00', 'I-BIXS', '1'),
```

I need to update two columns which are by default set to NULL: "free_seats", "luggage_space"
Both this values are contained inside the plane table.

The best thing to do would be setting those values to default the same as in the other table, but this does not seem possible. So, I tried with a trigger but as it seems I am not allowed to update a table while accessing in a trigger. I also tried calling a procedure inside the trigger, but the same error accours (Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'flight' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

This is what I tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER set_dfflight
AFTER INSERT
ON flightFOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE flight
    INNER JOIN plane on plane.reg=flight.plane
    SET flight.free_seats = plane.seats
         , flight.luggage_space = plane.luggage_space;
END$$
```

The columns are not foreign keys, as they must have the same values only at the insert.

This is how a plane instance is like:

```
  reg                 name               seats   luggage_space
('I-BIXS', 'AIRBUS INDUSTRIE-A 321-112', '245', '145'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't `UPDATE` the table the trigger was run for, because this risks creating an infinite loop.

You can modify fields in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, but not an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_dfflight
BEFORE INSERT
ON flight FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE fs INT;
    DECLARE ls INT;

    SELECT seats, luggage_space INTO fs, ls
    FROM plane
    WHERE plane.reg = NEW.plane;

    SET NEW.free_seats = fs;
    SET NEW.luggage_space = ls;
END
```

Comment: How an I do this with a before insert if he row does not exist yet?

Comment: I just added an example. Reference the columns of the new row to be created using the `NEW` keyword.

Comment: Read the documentation for more details about using the `NEW` and `OLD` keywords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html